# Has anyone purchased an AcoustiRack?

Tags: rack, rackmount, cooling

Looking for first hand experience with an AcoustiRack. Noise is fairly important.  The main concern is heat.  The unit will have a few Dell servers r510, r620, VRTX fully loaded, 2 APC UPS 2200va.

Any other suggestions for a rack that can house this configuration within an office would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have direct AcoustiRack experience, but I have used the APC variant and own the [GizMac XRackPro2](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwhite/7295339600/in/photostream/), another noise-reducing cabinet option. The XRackPro is able to run G6/G7/Gen8 HP servers in my living room without noticeable noise.

The Dell R510/R620 and UPS units won't be major contributors to noise. I don't think cooling would be a problem at reasonable ambient temperature either. I haven't seen what the VRTX's acoustic footprint is, but can I inquire about the non-technical solutions?

- Do these systems *need* to be in-house and in an area where the noise will be disruptive to users? (these days, this type of workload could easily be co-located)
- Have you considered a low-tech option like a cubicle wall to baffle sound (in addition to the rack)?

There is a reseller who promotes [several lines of quiet rack solutions](http://www.acoustiproducts.com/en/quiet_rack_cabinets.asp). Call and ask for more info.

Comment: we currently have a standard APC rack operating in the office.  Noise is decent but could be quieter.  My bigger concern is heat.  Low tech isn't an option for the office configuration.

Comment: In searching I found very little information on the AcoustiRack other than marketing.  It looks decent for the heat issue.

Comment: Modern servers can withstand higher ambient temps. The XRackPro unit I have has several fans inside the enclosure, but I don't use them. I don't think any of the devices you've listed would be outside the heat envelope of the AcoustiRack. But contact a [vendor/reseller to ask about specifics](http://www.acoustiproducts.com/en/quiet_rack_cabinets.asp).